# Simulate network latency between application in AKS and PostgreSQL server in Azure

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, latency, azure-aks

I need to test a scenario to see how my app deals with latency. My application is in K8S on Azure (AKS) and its connecting to a Postgres DB in Azure. Anyone know of any good tools that aren't too tricky to implement?

Comment: https://sysdig.com/blog/golden-signals-kubernetes/

Comment: could you please update the status of question mark it as resolve that's how SO works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up created a haproxy VM and directing my db traffic through it. Then on the haproxy I used the network emulator linux tool to delay the traffic . It works really well

https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem

Answer (score 1):

[pgbench](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbench.html) is the simplest to use with lots of information on the web to use this command.

Answer (score 1):

For simple Ping and latency check you can use the normal docker image **Busybox** and check the latency across the Network.

You can also use the Prometheus to monitor, like

```
pg_stat_activity_max_tx_duration is one metrics type.
```

You can read more at [here](https://sysdig.com/blog/postgresql-monitoring/)

To check POD network communication : https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/hardway/test-networking

You can also check out tools like [datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/postgresql-monitoring/)  which will expose the good details like latency and performance metrics.

**Extra** :

Dont forget to check out the [Pgbouncer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-pgbouncer)  if your team facing the latency issue.